# URL query parameters don't change anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `<Main/>` component which holds filter state in it.

```jsx
function Main() {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  function getFilter(string, date) {
    setFilter(string);
    setDate(date);
  }
   return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <SearchBar onChange={getFilter} season={date} />
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/:id/teams/:teamsId"
          render={(props) => <Team season={date} filter={filter} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/:id/teams"
          render={(props) => <TeamList filter={filter} date={date} />}
        />
```

`getFilter()` is function that passed to `<SearchBar/>` in order to change state.

```jsx
function SearchBar(props) {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.href);
    const date = params.get("date");
    const name = params.get("name");
    console.log(name);
    console.log(date);
    if (name) {
      setSearch(name);
    }
    if (date) {
      handleDateChange(new Date(date));
    }
    props.onChange(search, selectedDate);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  function handleChange(e) {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  }
  function submitAction(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.onChange(search, selectedDate);
    const currUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
    currUrl.searchParams.set("date", format(selectedDate, "yyyy"));
    currUrl.searchParams.set("name", search);
    window.history.pushState({}, "", currUrl);
    setSearch("");
  }
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardContent>
        <form onSubmit={submitAction} method="GET">
          <TextField
            value={search}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />

          <DatePicker
            onChange={handleDateChange}
            value={selectedDate}
          />
          <button type="submit">Поиск</button>
        </form>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

`getFilter()` runs every time form is submited or page is refreshed (in order to get URL query parameters). When I submit form it works just as intended. But when I reload page - i get query parameters, but filter state of `Main` is still empty string. Also for some reason `params.get("date")` always null

Comment: Whenever I see `// eslint-disable-next-line` on a `useEffect` hook's dependency array, I raise an eyebrow. Furthermore, you're saying there's some stale state in your app, which _further_ suggests to me your `useEffect` hook is not running when it should. My recommendation is to make it work without the eslint disable comment and I bet it'll fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks! It is works now. Not all dependencies were needed but anyway. And may you also help with null date? I don't understand why it is always returns null even with query params like ```?date=2021&name=```

Comment: Also now when I submit form useEffect runs 4 times for some reason. And other chunk of code now in loop. useEffect runs again and again and again